# training loss decreases while dev loss increases

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm observing the following patterns in a one-layer CNN, binary classification model:

1. Training loss decreases while dev loss increased with number of steps
2. Training accuracy increases while dev accuracy decreases with number of steps

Based on past SO questions and literature review, it seems that these patterns are indicative of over-fitting (the model performs well in training, but cannot generalize to new examples).

The graphs below illustrate the loss and accuracy with respect to the number of steps in training.

In both,

- The **orange** line represents the summary of the dev set performance.
- The **blue** line represents the summary of the training set performance.

Loss:
[image: Loss]

Accuracy:
[image]

Traditional remedies I've considered, and my observations about them:

- **Adding L2 Regularization** : I've tried many coefficients of L2 regularization -- from 0.0 to 4.5; all of these tests yield a similar pattern by the 5,000th step in both loss and accuracy.
- **Cross validation** : It seems that the role of cross-validation is widely mis-understood online. As [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/how-to-choose-a-predictive-model-after-k-fold-cross-validation) answer states, cross-validation is for model checking, not model building. Indeed, cross-validation would be a way to check if the model generalizes well. And actually, the graphs I show are from one fold of a 4-fold cross-validation. If I observe a similar pattern in the loss/accuracy in all the folds, what other insight does cross-validation offer other than the confirmation that the model does not generalize well?
- **Early stopping** : This would seem the most intuitive, but the loss graph seems to indicate that the loss levels out only after a divergence in the dev set loss is observed; the starting point of this early stop, then, doesn't seem easy to decide.
- **Data** : The amount of labeled data I have available is limited, so training on more data is not an option right now.

All this said, what I am asking is:

1. If the patterns observed in the loss and accuracy are indeed indicative of over-fitting, are there any other methods to counteract over-fitting that I haven't considered?
2. If these patterns are not indicative of over-fitting, what else could they mean?

Thanks -- any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are totally on the right track. Looks like classic over-fitting.

One option is adding dropout if you don't already have it. It falls into the category of regularization, but it is more commonly used now then L1 and L2 regularization.

Changing the model architcture could get better results but it's hard to say what specifically would be best. It could help to make it deeper with more layers and possibly some pooling layers. It will likely still overfit but you might get a higher accuracy on the dev set before that happens.

Getting more data may be one of the best things you could do. If you can't get more data you can try to augment the data. You can also try cleaning the data to remove noise which can help prevent the model from fitting to noise.

You may ultimately want to try setting up a hyperparameter optimization search. This, however, can take a while on neural nets which take a while to train. Make sure you remove a test set before hyper parameter tuning.